# Referencing one java script library from another

Tags: external, javascript

I'm just getting started defining and implementing external javaScript libraries and I'm a little confused by the rules. Below is the contents of three files "top.js", "bottom.js", and "ref.html". The file "bottom.js" contains a reference to "top.js" and the file "ref.html" contains a reference to "bottom.js". In "ref.html" I have attempted to access functions in "top.js" by directly calling function and by calling the function via another function in "bottom.js", neither approach seems to be working. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

topTest.js:

```
function top_test() {
alert('Test from top');
}
```

bottom.js

```
function bottom() {
alert("bottom");
top_test();
}

loadScript('topTest.js');    // Call function (function declarations are evaluated
                     //   before the rest of the code, so this works)

function loadScript(file_name) {
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');

// Reference to the latest (this) <script> tag in the document
scripts = scripts[scripts.length-1];

// Set target
newScript.src = file_name;

// Clean-up code:
newScript.onload = newScript.onerror = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};

// Insert script in the document, to load it.
scripts.parentNode.insertBefore(newScript, scripts);
```

}

ref.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bottom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
test
<script type="text/javascript">
bottom();
top();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<script>` tags have to be removed from the `.js` files.

These tags are **only** needed inside a HTML document, used to mark a part of the content as a script. The whole content of a JavaScript file is JavaScript, so adding the `<script>` tags do not make any sense, and is therefore invalid.

To include a JavaScript from within a script in the `<head>`, you can use a library, or one the following method:

Create a `<script>` tag using `document.createElement`, and insert the script in the document. Example of your **`bottom.js`**:

```
function bottom() {
    alert("bottom");
    top();
}
loadScript('top.js');    // Call function (function declarations are evaluated
                         //   before the rest of the code, so this works)

function loadScript(file_name) {
    if (document.readyState === 'loading') { // Chrome
        document.write('<script src="' + file_name.replace(/"/g, '&quot;') + '"></script>');
        return;
    }
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');

    // Reference to the latest (this) <script> tag in the document
    scripts = scripts[scripts.length-1];

    // Set target
    newScript.src = file_name;

    // Clean-up code:
    newScript.onload = newScript.onerror = function() {
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    };

    // Insert script in the document, to load it.
    scripts.parentNode.insertBefore(newScript, scripts);
}
```

Comment: This is part of the answer; you might also want to explain how to "include" a JS file in another JS file. [`*cough*`](http://requirejs.org/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have removed the tags (edited in the code above) and it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @user996035 See updated answer for the contents of `bottom.js`.

Comment: I have attempted to implement your suggestion (see code edits). The block marked "//Clean up code" seems to have a problem (I tried removing the semi-colon at the end of the function and that didn't fix it). With that line commented out the function in "top.js" is still not getting called. Any further help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user996035 I accidentally put a colon, `:`, instead of a semicolon, `;`, at the end of the code. It works correctly now.

Comment: I have replaced the colon with a semi-colon (reflected in code edit above). That line no longer stops the script but the top(); is still not executing. I'm working to get this sorted out but if any one see's the problem help would be appreciated.

Comment: @user996035 In Firefox 11, this works fine. **However**, in Chrome, your code does **not** work. That is caused by the fact that [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.top) is an existing, **read-only** variable. You **have to** use another function name, e.g. `function top_test() {alert('Test from top');}`.

Comment: I edited you're suggested alterations into the code above (Re-Naming the function "top_test()" and the .js file "topTest.js"). It does work on Firefox 10.0.2 but it still does not work on Chrome 17.0.963.79 or Safari 5.1.3. Am I missing something? Are you saying that "top" is a special reserved name?

Comment: @user996035 It's a pre-defined global property, which refers to the top window. Don't forget to also replace `top()` in ref.html` with `top_test();`. I have also updated my answer with working code for Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use html tags in `.js` files. Just plain javascript codes

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have edited the code above to incorporate your suggestion and still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You cannot use function in `.js` file that defined an other `.js` file. All must be used in html which both js must linked